# Console based folder locking app

Tags: python

I'm new to programming. I wrote this following code in Python. It's a simple script that locks and unlocks a folder (basic functionality of a folder-lock) with a password. I hope someone could suggest me to improve the code and make it shorter. Currently, it can lock single folder; however, I wanna make it multi-threading so that it can work on more than one directory. Any suggestion or advice in this regard will be highly appreciated.

```
r""" FolderLockV1.py: A simple python script to lock a folder with a password """

import os
import sys
import stat
import shutil
import ctypes
import hashlib


__author__ = 'AJ'
__version__ = '1.0.0'


TEMP_LOCATION = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop', 'TEMP_FOLDER')  # dir path where target will be hidden
PASS_FILE = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop/TEMP_FOLDER', 'password.txt')  # password file
FILE_PATH_CURRENT_FOLDER_TEXT_FILE = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop/TEMP_FOLDER', 'current_folder.txt')


def hash_data(data):
    """ A function that returns hashed data, here sha512 hashing has been implemented """

    encrypt_data = data.encode('utf-8')
    hashed = hashlib.sha512(encrypt_data).hexdigest()
    return hashed


def current_fold_path_fetcher():
    """ Returns folder_path input from the user """

    while True:
        x = input('Path to the folder you wish to lock\n>>> ')
        if os.path.exists(x):
            return x
        print('Not a valid folder path')


def store_retrieve_info(file_path, **kwargs):
    """ A modified function for writing and reading texts to/from text files """

    if len(kwargs) < 1:
        print('Need to provide kwarg(s)')
    if 'text' in kwargs:
        with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
            f.write(kwargs['text'])
    if 'read' in kwargs:
        if kwargs['read'] is True:
            with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
                x = f.read()
                return x


def folder_lock():
    """ One of the core functions, it basically locks(rather moves) the folder to a secret path """

    fold_path = current_fold_path_fetcher()
    global FILE_PATH_CURRENT_FOLDER_TEXT_FILE
    store_retrieve_info(FILE_PATH_CURRENT_FOLDER_TEXT_FILE, text=fold_path)  # writes current dir path to txt file
    pass_word = input('password\n>>> ')
    pass_word_hashed = hash_data(pass_word)  # inputted password is being hashed
    global PASS_FILE
    store_retrieve_info(PASS_FILE, text=pass_word_hashed)  # writes hashed password in a text file
    global TEMP_LOCATION
    shutil.move(fold_path, TEMP_LOCATION)  # moves current dir to the temp dir to make it visualize as locked
    print('Folder Locked')


def folder_unlock():
    """ The other core function that unlocks the target dir """

    global PASS_FILE
    global TEMP_LOCATION
    global FILE_PATH_CURRENT_FOLDER_TEXT_FILE
    current_folder_path_from_file = str(store_retrieve_info(FILE_PATH_CURRENT_FOLDER_TEXT_FILE, read=True))  # reads
    #  current folder path from stored txt file
    current_folder_in_temp = TEMP_LOCATION + '\\' + current_folder_path_from_file.rsplit('\\', 1)[-1]  # recreates the
    #  old dir path where the hidden dir was initially located
    in_pass = input('Password\n>>> ')
    in_pass_hashed = hash_data(in_pass)  # inputted password by the user is being hashed for verification
    read_password = str(store_retrieve_info(PASS_FILE, read=True))  # loads the saved password in the memory
    if in_pass_hashed == read_password:  # matches inputted password with stored one
        shutil.move(current_folder_in_temp, current_folder_path_from_file)  # moves target dir to it's original path
        print('fokder unlocked')
        remove_file()  # removes the temp folder and it's contents
    else:
        print('incorrect pass')


def initial_checkups():
    """ An initial checkup function that makes sure that a temp dir exists """

    global TEMP_LOCATION
    if os.path.exists(TEMP_LOCATION):
        pass
    else:
        os.makedirs(TEMP_LOCATION)
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW(TEMP_LOCATION, 0x02)  # changes file-mode to hidden, 0x01 value to
        #  make it visible


def remove_file():
    """ A supporting function that removes temp dir and it's contents """

    #  There are three options to make it happen, only option 2 has been chosen

    # global PASS_FILE
    # global FILE_PATH_CURRENT_FOLDER_TEXT_FILE
    global TEMP_LOCATION

    #  option 1: remove each file then changing file-mode of the folder, then remove dir

    # os.remove(PASS_FILE)
    # os.remove(FILE_PATH_CURRENT_FOLDER_TEXT_FILE)
    # os.chmod(TEMP_LOCATION, stat.S_IWRITE)
    # os.rmdir(TEMP_LOCATION)

    #  option 2: change file-mode and then remove dir

    os.chmod(TEMP_LOCATION, stat.S_IWRITE)  # changes file attribute to writable i.e., make it not readonly dir
    shutil.rmtree(TEMP_LOCATION)  # removes temp dir

    #  option 3: remove dir and it's contents without changing any file-mode, more direct approach

    # os.system('rmdir /S /Q "{}"'.format(TEMP_LOCATION))


def get_choice():
    """ A function that return user choices """

    while True:
        choice_input = input('Press "L" to lock folder\nPress "U" to unlock folder\n'
                             'Press "Q" to quit application').lower()
        if choice_input in {'l', 'u', 'q'}:
            return choice_input
        print('Wrong option selected')


def main():
    print('Welcome to FolderLocker V0.1 by AJ\n')
    initial_checkups()  # creates temp dir
    choice_made = get_choice()
    if choice_made == 'l':
        folder_lock()
    if choice_made == 'u':
        try:
            folder_unlock()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print('You NEED TO LOCK a folder before you try unlocking it!!!')
            os.system('pause')  # allows user to read console message
    else:
        sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I have upgraded your beautiful program locker with the possibility to add more than one folder and I will add more option, if possible i would you like to collaborate with you for this project, what do you think about it?
Please contact me.